# Getting undesired number of sections from fetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm having an issue getting a `tableView` to update properly, though I've made some progress. I think the source if my trouble lies in my `fetchedResultsController` returning an undesired number of sections.

My objective is to have the `SongSequences` displayed in one section sorted by `songSequenceTitle`. What I've done with my `fetchedResultsController` ends up treating each `SongSequence` as a new section.

I have `Songs` that are added to a `SongSequence` as an `NSOrderedSet`. Here's what my `NSManagedObjects` look like:

```
extension SongSequence {

    @NSManaged var songSequenceTitle: String!
    @NSManaged var songs: NSOrderedSet!

}

extension Song {

    @NSManaged var favorite: NSNumber!
    @NSManaged var songDescription: String!
    @NSManaged var songFilename: String!
    @NSManaged var songStar: String?
    @NSManaged var songSequences: NSOrderedSet!

}
```

When I pull them out of the `managedObjectContext`, my `fetchedResultsController` is seeing each `SongSequence` as a separate section, which is wreaking havoc on my `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate methods and `tableView` update methods when the `managedObjectContext` changes.

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController = {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "SongSequence")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "songSequenceTitle", ascending: true);
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController (fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: "songSequenceTitle", cacheName: nil)

    frc.delegate = self

    return frc
}()
```

I'm stumped as to why the `fetchedResultsController` is seeing each `SongSequence` as a separate section.

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    print("PlaylistVC numberOfSectionsInTableView = \(fetchedResultsController.sections!.count)")
    // This is equal to the number of SongSequences in my MOC
    return fetchedResultsController.sections!.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // This is always 1
    let numberOfRowsInSection = fetchedResultsController.sections?[section].numberOfObjects
    return numberOfRowsInSection!
}
```

How can I display all the `SongSequences` in a single section?

Comment: Do you want all the song sequences to be in one section?

Comment: Thank you for reading! Yes, my goal is to have the `SongSequences` in one section sorted by the `songSequenceTitle`. I'll update the post to make that clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fetched results controller, you specified a [non-nil `sectionNameKeyPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFetchedResultsController/initWithFetchRequest:managedObjectContext:sectionNameKeyPath:cacheName:).  This is grouping song sequences by title, and since each song sequence title is distinct, each one appears in its own section.

> A key path on result objects that returns the section name. Pass nil to indicate that the controller should generate a single section.

Initialize your frc by setting the `sectionNameKeyPath` to nil, to avoid grouping the song sequences by section.

```
let frc = NSFetchedResultsController (fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
```

Comment: Unreal! I feel so dumb right now ;) Right after you mentioned that, I went back and changed it to `nil` and it worked. Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction!